# Choosing a better form for numerical integration

Tags: integration

Consider two form of integrals:
$$\int_0^\infty r^k e^{-\lambda_1r-\lambda_2r^2-\lambda_3r^3-\lambda_4r^4} dr \tag{1}$$and $$\int_0^{\infty}r^k e^{\frac{c_1r-c_2 r^2-c_3r^3}{(1+g*r)}}dr\tag{2}$$
I want to know which of these are better for numerical integration? because in a paper which I'm trying reproduce its results, it has been suggested to use Power-Pade approximant which replaces (1) by (2) namely $$\sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n r^n\approx\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{c_nr^n}{(1+g*r)^{N-3}}\tag{3}$$ In fact I set $N=4$ in (1) and (2) to simplify the expressions.

I have tried both by a Mathematica code (`NIntegrate` command and different methods and ranges) but they return error and show a very unstable behavior. It turns out that they are not well-behave at all and it is necessary to modify them or transform to other things (Methods such as Gauss-Laguerre quadrature) So my two main questions are:

1. Which form is more appropriate to numerical integration? (1) or (2)?
2. How can I modify the better form (answer of question 1) to obtain a stable behavior?

Thanks a lot.